# Win7 freeze/crash at random after all updates finish

Tags: windows-7, freeze, windows-update

Already a couple of months I have that my computer starts freezing (screen stays on but nothing moves anymore, wont come out of this condition) after windows update. I reverted with system restore to the previous state and then all is ok. But I want my updates of course...

How can I find out what is causing this? It's a Win 7 pro n x64.

Note that the problem appears when restarting after windows update around 5th.June. What do I do when there are not enough versions to restore to ?

Comment: I'd probably give [antifreeze](http://www.resplendence.com/antifreeze) a shot - its a task manager designed to handle such situations. I've not actually tried it myself yet, but it looks like a possibly useful tool in that situation

Comment: It seems your input devices have to work for that, my system completely freezes. But thanks, nice to know about this program

Comment: Also, anything in your event logs around that time? Could you try using [wsus offline updates](http://download.wsusoffline.net/) to update?

Comment: offline updates are not needed, it finishes all updates. Only after that, random freezes, sometimes a whole day without and sometimes a couple a day. Errorlog only has a message about resetting the system *power may be lost* something like that.

Comment: probably will have to install one update at a time to figure out which one is causing the problem.

Comment: The fun part: I have this problem since december I believe, but Windows update says last time that updates are installed is May 23, and all updates are published June 4 or later. I really don't understand... And no, auto update is disabled.

Answer (score -1):

For that sort of problem i would do a full backup and wipe, i have spent days on similar issues .. clean machine and image before you run updates and afterwards using one of these

http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-drive-imaging-program.htm

Comment: We usual like more then a single sentence with a link to an application here on Superuser.